# multicollinearity question, X and X change score

Tags: multicollinearity

Consider survey data from surgeries. $Y$ represents observed surgical 
quality and is measured post-surgery; $X$ represents perceived surgical 
difficulty level and is measured pre and post surgery.

It is desired to assess the relationship between $Y$ and $X_{pre}$ and also $Y$ 
on $X_{\delta} = X_{post} - X_{pre}$. However, since $X_\delta$ is derived from 
$X_{pre}$, we know that $X_{pre}$ and $X_{\delta}$ will be highly correlated.    One 
option is to attempt to reduce such multicollinearity via centering.
Any thoughts on alternative strategies and pros/cons?   This scenario 
sounds similar to the commonly discussed scenario of how to handle 
change scores via ANCOVA (e.g., Senn 2009, Stat Med) when we have change 
scores with respect to $Y$, but it is different since here we have no 
baseline $Y$ and a change score for $X$.

Comment: Are you sure of the high correlation?  It is not necessarily the case that X.pre and X.delta will be correlated at all.  Also, is it necessary for X.pre and X.delta to appear within the same analysis?